# Detach App from Google Play

Tags: android

I have an OpenSource App on my SGS2 with OS 2.3.5 (root) which I want to detach from Google Play. I don't want that Google Play shows me Updates for this App anymore.

What do I need to do, to get this app out of Google Play, let's say to make the app different from the one in Google Play which will be updated by the Google Servers?

Since Google Market changed to Google Play, the information for Updates and Apps are not anymore stored on the device but on Google Play servers, that makes it not possible to detach an app from Google Play anymore.
I think it is hardly possible to detach an app which is closed source but when I have the source, at least I could compile it and change things, but what at least?

Hope someone could help me here, I tried to post in android-dev Mailinglist, but this question might be too much a beginner-question.

Thank you.

frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23862/how-to-hide-updates-from-market-given-titanium-backup-detach-from-market-doe) in another forum post. The last answer from ce4 does the trick.

With the app Zipsigner2 I can sign the app with another key (autotestkey). First I make a backup with titanium (this gives me a gz-file which I can unzip with ES) then I sign this apk with Zipsigner2 using the autotestkey. Now I can re-install the app and Google play doesn't try to update, not thinking it is the same app anymore.

If the Zipsigner solution doesn't work, e.g. an app "Swype" will crash then always and wont work, there is another solution from Firelord in 
[How to get rid of update notifications for a given app in Google Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/114815/24154)
I use this now as a Tasker Task hourly and it seems to work.
Thank Firelord!

Comment: One important thing: first I need to uninstall the original signed app, only then I can re-install my self-signed app.

Comment: Since this I found the other post with the Titanium Backup Pro solution: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/110135/96277

Answer (score -2):

once check [`Uninstalling Android apps`](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2521768)

[`You can now update, uninstall Android apps via Google Play site`](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57462148-285/you-can-now-update-uninstall-android-apps-via-google-play-site/)

Comment: I don't want to uninstall the app, I just don't want any updates from google play.